# How do I make and assign a rect to a sprite in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

I already have a simple game engine built where the player and enemy classes are only objects.
I would like to make them sprites so that I can check for collison and just generally manage them better, but I can't seem to find any good examples on how to do this...
I have extended both the player and enemy classes to extend `pygame.sprite.Sprite` classes.
But when I checked for the collision between the two,
It said that the two classes need `rects` (rectangles).

I am unaware of how to do this...

Comment: For tutorials of sprites with collisions view: http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html , http://kai.vm.bytemark.co.uk/~piman/writing/sprite-tutorial.shtml ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sprites are objects, everything you need is already included as fields in the sprite class. You need to explicitly set the bounding rectangles for the sprites.

from the pygame docs:

> pygame.sprite.spritecollide find Sprites in a Group that intersect
>   another Sprite pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, dokill,
>   collided = None): return Sprite_list
>
> Return a list containing all Sprites in a Group that intersect with
>   another Sprite. Intersection is determined by comparing the
>   Sprite.rect attribute of each Sprite.

So you need to set sprite.rect to the rectangle that you want your sprite collision to be based on. Normaly you can use the size of your sprite image as your collision rectangle.

```
s.image = pygame.image.load("sprite.png").convert() #load a sprite image
s.rect = b.image.get_rect() # set collision rectangle
```

Comment: i am getting this error now, and i have given both classes a self.rect var, i dont understand this.... if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(Player.Rect, Enemy.Rect) == True:
AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'Rect'

Comment: Post your class code. Sounds like your player/enemy constructors don't call sprite / set rect. And the code would be `if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player.rect, enemy.rect): print 'yes'`

Comment: i only put self.rect = self.image.get_rect() in my __init__ function....whats the correct way to assign the rect attribute?

Comment: do you load your image correctly? you can print your rect right after assigning it in your init to see if it prints correctly.